# How to deal with a "low search volume" keyword on AdWords

Tags: google-ads-api

Let say I made a print ad for a product, where I ask viewer to search online for a specific keyword to know more about it.

Before publishing the ad, I want to make sure my promotional website will shows up on top google search result by purchasing the keyword via AdWords, but this keyword has a "Low search volume" and is not elegible.

Google says that:
"Users don't search for this term very often on Google properties, so it's not eligible to trigger your ads. If this is a term that you expect to increase in popularity soon (like a new brand name), then you don't need to do anything; the keyword will start triggering ads automatically. Otherwise, we recommend trying Keyword Planner to find different keyword ideas to increase the traffic to your campaign. Learn more about building an effective keyword list"

So my question is:

Is waiting really the best thing I can do ?
I know once the print ad will be out, search will start to increase and the keyword will become elegible. But Google says it can take up to 1 week for them to update their elegible keyword list, which means for 1 week, consumer will search for this keyword without finding my ad which is quite a waste. Is there a way I can avoid that ?

Answer (score 2):

There really isn't much else to be done. You are at the mercy of Google (as always) as to when they allow you to show an ad on thier platform.

It isnt a 'waste' as such, however, because you won't pay for traffic unless or until there is enough to show for.

Comment: thanks for your reply. The waste aspect is that if I print an ad, people won't find the search ads for about 1 week.

Comment: Is there some known technic to artificially trigger searches so that Google remove this "low search volume" flag in order to be prepared for the launch of the print ad maybe ?